# past / future -- "抜けたら" -- 「国境の長いトンネルを抜けると雪国であった」

Tags: tense, past, future, literature, relative-tense

[Other uses of the particle と: トンネルを抜けると雪国であった](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32407/16344)

1. 「国境の長いトンネルを抜けると雪国であった」

   抜ける looks like present (but we know it's past) -- What is the usual explantion for this ?

2. 「国境の長いトンネルを抜けたら雪国であった」 <--- Here 抜けたら looks like past, but this must be an illusion, because ...

   「もう１０分くらいして、国境の長いトンネルを抜けたら窓を開けましょうね。」 <--  Here 抜けたら is talking about the future.  Or is this "past" from the future vantage point?

---

相対テンス https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_and_absolute_tense

If there is a super-clear, concise explanation, i'd like to see it.
(preferably in Jp).

http://blog.livedoor.jp/robinsonrobin/archives/8036910.html

> http://kamome.2ch.net/test/read.cgi/gengo/1291717138/
>
> 152 ：名無し象は鼻がウナギだ！：2011 >>150
> 日本語の時制は相対テンスなので、複文では、従属節が主節に対して前の出来事か後の出来事かで
> 従属節の動詞を過去にしたり非過去にしたりする。（英語は絶対テンスなので、現在から見て前か後かで時制を使い分ける）

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/39644/16344
[ the difference between 行く and 行った in Japanese is not a difference of "tense"（時制）, it is a difference of "aspect"（相）.]  <<<----- That's kind-of an eye-opening statement. Is that well-explained in a past Jp.SE post, or in a convenient Web page ? (I prefer a Jp Web page)

Comment: `国境の長いトンネルを抜けたら窓を開けましょうね` means `Once we have...`

Comment: Today, I saw three tense question.

Answer (score 2):

The expression of 日本へ行く前に has all possiblities of past, present and future.

> future:日本へ行く前におみやげを買った。これから日本へ行きます。
>
> present:日本へ行く前におみやげを買った。いま飛行機に乗っています。
>
> past:日本へ行く前におみやげを買った。だからこれをあなた(日本の友達)にあげます。

Answer (score 2):

抜けたら has nothing to do with past tense.

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 452:
"たら is a subordinate conjunction which indicates that the action/state expressed by the main clause  in a sentence takes place after the action/state expressed by the subordinate clause."

Examples:
山田さんが来たら、私は帰る。
If Mr. Yamada comes, I will go home.

In the example above, 来たら is not  past tense, it is talking about the future.